# PHP include within wordpress not connecting to an external database

Tags: php, wordpress

I am including a PHP page on a wordpres post with a wordpress plugin, the code on my included page is:

```
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass"); 
mysql_select_db("dbname",$conn);

if(!function_exists("ContactLookup")) {
    function ContactLookup($sequence) {
        global $conn;
        $sql="SELECT * from contacts where sequence = '".$sequence."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

but its returning error:

```
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in index.php on line 93
line 93 = $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Im not too sure why i receive this error because i have put `$conn` as a global variable in the PHP function and i have tested the database connection which works fine

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions in new code, they are deprecated and will likely be removed at a future point. Consider using PDO or `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: i will be changing to PDO, i find it easier to debug using mysql_

Comment: i have tried but cannot work it out. thats why I'm asking on here.. i never said 'i can debug everything myself' did i?

Comment: Is the mysql database connectivity same as Wordpress `wp-config.php`? Or its separate database connection?

Comment: its a separate DB connection, i am including a page called index.php in another directory and that index.php page has the db connection ($conn) string and the functions etc

Answer (score 0):

rename the $conn variable to something else. 
check this example:

```
$mysqlConn = null;
function ConnectToMysql() {
    $mysqlConn=mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("dbname",$mysqlConn) or die(mysql_error());
}

if(!function_exists("ContactLookup")) {
    function ContactLookup($sequence) {
        global $mysqlConn;
        if(!$mysqlConn) ConnectToMysql(); // reconnect and reinit connection variable if somewhere it have been changed

        $sql="SELECT * from contacts where sequence = '".$sequence."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$mysqlConn) or die(mysql_error());
        $result=mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

P.S. I know my answer is not brilliant. I not fond of using mysql_* commands. but that's a quick fix.

Comment: I think the problem with connection. that's why I've added  or die(mysql_error());  to connection. look for changes in my answer.

Comment: also try to change "localhost" to "127.0.0.1" maybe there is no permission in mysql.user table for "localhost" - by name, so try with ip address. also create test.php file to check your code.

Comment: if i don't use functions the db connection string works fine so it seems like the connection is not being passed into the function